# Sort and limit number of bars to display on bargraph

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart

I have a dataset of traffic violations and want to display only the top 10 violations per month on a bargraph.  Can I limit the number of bars after sorting values to display only the top 10? There are 42 different column names of traffic violations.

```
month_jan = df[df.MonthName == "Jan"]
month_jan[feature_cols].sum().sort_values(ascending=0).plot(kind='bar')
```

`Feature_cols` is a list of all 42 column names that correspond to traffic violations.

Thanks!

Comment: `month_jan[feature_cols].sum().sort_values(ascending=0)[:10].plot(kind='bar')`

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
month_jan[feature_cols].sum().sort_values(ascending=0)[:10].plot(kind='bar')
```

Answer (score 0):

`Series` objects have a `.head` method, just like `DataFrame`s ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.head.html)).
This allows you to select the top N items very elegantly with `data.head(N)`.
Here's a complete working example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'feature1': [0, 1, 2, 3],
    'feature2': [2, 3, 4, 5],
    'MonthName': ['Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Feb']
})
feature_cols = ['feature1', 'feature2']

month_jan = df[df.MonthName == "Jan"]
top10 = month_jan[feature_cols].sum().sort_values(ascending=0).head(10)
top10.plot(kind='bar')
```