# Matplotlib, limiting number of bars in chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn

How do I truncate a bar chart to only show the top 10 bars, and leave out the rest?
The array it's drawn from will be different sizes based on features selected, but often will be too many to display usefully.  So I want to set a max.

```
nFeatures = dataSample.select_dtypes(include=['int64', 'float64']).columns
cFeatures = dataSample.select_dtypes(include=['category']).columns

ohe = (mainPipe.named_steps['preprocessor']
         .named_transformers_['cat']
         .named_steps['onehot'])
feature_names = ohe.get_feature_names(input_features=cFeatures)
feature_names = np.r_[feature_names, nFeatures]

tree_feature_importances = (
    mainPipe.named_steps['classifier'].feature_importances_)
sorted_idx = tree_feature_importances.argsort()

y_ticks = np.arange(0, len(feature_names))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.barh(y_ticks, tree_feature_importances[sorted_idx])
ax.set_yticklabels(feature_names[sorted_idx])
ax.set_yticks(y_ticks)
ax.autoscale(tight=True)
ax.set_title("Random Forest Feature Importances")
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: barchart]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38338396/sort-and-limit-number-of-bars-to-display-on-bargraph

Comment: @Kaushal28 Saw that, i tried [:10] and also .head(10) but neither worked, but also possible that I don't know the right place to pass that.

Comment: `ax.barh(y_ticks[:10], tree_feature_importances[sorted_idx][:10])`

Comment: If both are python/numpy lists

Comment: That half works, it gives me a list of 10 labels on the left, but no bars displayed.

I tried adding

`ax.set_yticklabels(feature_names[sorted_idx][:10])`
`ax.set_yticks(y_ticks[:10])`

but didn't help.

Comment: try printing `type(tree_feature_importances[sorted_idx]))`

Comment: This should be python/numpy list

Comment: Yes, prints as `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Comment: Whats the dimension? Search for how to slice numpy nd array on specific dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Use iloc.

```py
df.iloc[0:10].plot.bar()
```